# Using pow in KotlinJS in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-js

There is a library called kotlin.math which contains a method pow:

```
import kotlin.math.pow
val factor = pow(10.0, 2)
print(factor)
```

and result:

```
100.0
```

However Intellij is not registering that I have imported the pow function, is there a special pow method for KotlinJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different versions of pow in KotlinJS.

The **deprecated** `kotlin.js.math.pow` which is defined as:

```
public fun pow(base: Double, exp: Double): Double
```

and the standard library version `kotlin.math.pow` which is defined as an extension function.

```
public actual inline fun Double.pow(n: Int): Double = nativeMath.pow(this, n.toDouble())
```

So your example has to be changed to look like this:

```
import kotlin.math.pow
val factor = 10.0.pow(2)
print(factor)
```